Odd issue when rigging
I was able to rig a model, but I'm having issues when moving bones. The model wasn't in a t-pose, the hands were clipped through the legs. I rigged the model, and whenever I move the hand for example, part of the leg mesh moves and distorts. Is there a fix for this?



Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

search for "weight painting", you will have to select your hand bones in vertex groups and manually remove weight in wrong spots to correct it

As MikoCG says you'll need to remove the vertices of the leg from the vertex group of the hand, you can do it in Weight Paint mode or through the Data panel:

